# Under the Laravel 7 (php7) system, if I query any id of my table, there is no result

Tags: php, laravel, database, php-7, laravel-7

Under the `Laravel 7 (php7)` system, if I query any id of my table, there is no result, but if I enter the id value as a string, then there is a result.

In the table, the `id column type` is `int(11)`. There is also the principle of primary key and index.

What could be the problem?

Not working:

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Working:

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id, '1')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the query builder is taking integer 1 as a boolean true value instead of a integer value, but when you write 1 as a string it simple matches the value in the column and not the datatype.